# What is the meaning of "nikah" and the purpose of marriage?

Tags: nikah, definitions

I heard that the word "nikah" has a disgusting meaning to it? All this time I thought "nikah" meant marriage, but apparently it means to have sex.

What is the main purpose of marriage in Islam? And what is the purpose of sex?

Does the man have ownership of the women's body? Which is why he pays the mahr?

EDIT: I asked the actual meaning of nikha and the main purpose as well.

(And souls do become one after marriage in Islam and both husband and wife continue being husband and wife in the world after. Their relationship is referred to an eternal bond.)

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Marriage is a sacred Covenent between two individuals. Allah created man and woman in pairs to stand by one another. As far as intimacy is concerned yes it does become allowed after marriage  (just like any other religion) however the purpose of it is not to have sexual relations. Marriage is mutal respect between one another, kindness love and support. It is an eternal bond. I have looked at the quran myself and nothing indicates to me that it has a disgusting meaning. Marriage is just unifying both individuals who were created form one soul for one another. A woman was created from the rib of man, she wasn't created from his food as she is not below him nor was she created from his head as she is not above him instead she was created from his side to support him, near the heart to be loved and near the arm ro be protected. People who think it has a disgusting meaning need to get a reality check and get your facts straight don't speak about something you have no knowledge about. The primary function or main purpose of marriage is to love and support one another.

Comment: Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

Making sex between the spouses legal is one important function of nikah. There are others as well (prospect of having offspring, mutual comfort, financial support for the wife), but marriage in Islam is not a sacrament with the same sacred status as in some other religions, it is a contract. [Sex between spouses is seen as sadaqa](https://sunnah.com/adab/11/7), as is [spending on your family](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/59), but it doesn't have the same two-souls-becoming-one-for-eternity sacredness about it as for example in Christianity. It is true that there are ahadith that say that husband and wife will be married in jannah if both should go there, but divorce is halal (even if societally - although not doctrinally - disliked), and a man is allowed to marry multiple women at once.

As for the husband owning the wife's body, that's not correct. He does however have wide-reaching rights over her, such as [determining where she lives](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37112/17702), whether she can [leave the house](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=116281), or whether she can take up a job [(see last three paragraphs here)](https://islamqa.info/en/22397), and having the right to [demand sex whenever he wants to](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/312/is-a-woman-required-to-have-sex-with-her-husband-whenever-he-requests-it) - barring a small number of valid reasons that she can cite to refuse sleeping with him; not being in the mood or not being attracted to him are not among those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Nikkah means intercourse - it's not an offensive word. Nikkah Nama means Nikah agreement- As sex is required for procreation therefore in Muslim marriage, both husband and wife are asked three times for consent to intercourse with witnesses so later on no one can claim rape.

So Muslim shouldn't be ashamed of word Nikkah

Answer (score -1):

Real meaning of nikah is metting of two soul and converting into  one

Comment: This post would be more helpful if it was elaborated and claims be supported by evidences

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works, and please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.

Answer (score -3):

nikah means marriage, I am a Muslim and it is disgusting and a disgrace that that is what you all think. I am so offended. what kinda of people are you all. nikah is an Indonesian word meaning marriage and if you don't believe me LOOK IT UP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For more information about this site and our model take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your post: First "nikah" is a word with an Arabic origin which maybe was adapted in the Indonesian language by accepting Islam by the majority there in. It refers to both marriage and intercourse. Secondly we have a [be nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) policy which each user should respect.

Comment: It‘s okay to be passionate in your love for the Deen, but you have to be rational in the way you answer someone‘s question in this Q&A forum. When you assert something explain your reasoning for the assertion and/or present you dalil (evidence) to prove the correctness of your claim. It also helps to be tactful and courteous as well. Otherwise, you come off looking like you‘re just ranting or throwing a temper tantrum which, of course, undermines your credibility among mature and serious thinkers. Ma‘as‘salaam.