# Conventions after divorce

Tags: talaq, children

What are the regulations after a husband definitely divorced regarding

- maintenance of the ex wife after waiting period if she is not re-married
- contact between minor children and their mother

I found a relevant question that remains but without an answer to my question:

[Who becomes protector and maintainer of a woman after divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/who-becomes-protector-and-maintainer-of-a-woman-after-divorce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maintenance is due on the same people who were responsible for it before her marriage. Such as her parents, children, siblings and other relatives who are her heirs.

  > يد المعطي العليا وابدأ بمن تعول أمك وأباك وأختك وأخاك ثم أدناك أدناك
  >
  > The hand which gives is the upper hand. Start with those for whom you are responsible; your mother, your father, your sister, your brother, then the next closest, and the next closet.
  >
  > <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2532)</sup>
- Not sure what the question is here. Both parents have the right to meet their child, as preventing that is breaking of ties which is haram.